# Poor device performance when redrawing views

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, nstimer

I'm using NSTimer to refresh 5 contexts and paste them onto 5 views every .03 seconds.  This worked fine in the simulator and ran at a great frame rate but then chugs when deployed on an iPod.  I dropped the rate down to .1 and saw little improvement.  Is there a more efficient way of redrawing these contexts?

Some code:

```
- (void)addViews{
[self.superview addSubview:mag];
[self.superview addSubview:vc];
[self.superview addSubview:na];
[self.superview addSubview:wave];
[self.superview addSubview:mon];

[self.superview addSubview:selector];

looper = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.03
                                target:self
                               selector:@selector(setNeeds)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];

[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:looper forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

-(void)setNeeds{
[mag setNeedsDisplay];
[vc setNeedsDisplay];
[na setNeedsDisplay];
[wave setNeedsDisplay];
[mon setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

This is the context adjustment applied to each view.  Essentially a magnifying glass.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
CGPoint magnifiedPoint = [viewToMagnify convertPoint:coordPoint fromView:self.superview];

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(context,(self.frame.size.width*0.5),(self.frame.size.height*0.5));
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.3, 1.3);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context,-1*(magnifiedPoint.x),-1*(magnifiedPoint.y));
[self.viewToMagnify.layer renderInContext:context];
}
```

Comment: Probably. It’s hard to be sure without seeing your code, though—care to elaborate?

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely an issue with redrawing the contexts onto the views.  I'm simply doing it to too many views too fast.  I wish I knew a more efficient method.

Comment: Obvious question: why the timer? Is there not some event (touch/drag to move the mag glass, underlying data changed etc.) that you could hook into instead of this polling mechanism you've built?

Comment: I could, but the glass is UIView with a fixed position over a viewPicker's value set.  It's purpose is to magnify the chosen values so I only really need it to update when the pickerView is in motion and settles on a value.  Unfortunately, there is no event handling for simple viewPicker interaction (ie, touching the picker).  Regardless, the refresh rate would still have to be pretty high to fluidly represent the area being magnified.  There just has to be a more efficient method than setNeedsDisplay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Graphics drawing is relatively slow because it's not hardware accelerated using OpenGL. For anything but the most trivial drawing, Core Graphics is too slow for real-time animation on iOS.

Core animation is much faster because it uses OpenGL hardware acceleration. I suggest trying to achieve your effect using Core animation as much as possible. Every UIView is backed by a CALayer so any transforms you apply to your view.transform property directly will be very fast. You can also dynamically mask a view using an image by setting the view.layer.mask property.

Perhaps you could simulate your magnification effect by scaling the view itself (or a copy of the view with the same content) and masking it to a circle. That way you wouldn't ever have to call renderInContext or do any CGContext drawing, and the whole thing should run at a decent frame rate.

Comment: This is very sound advice and may even be the answer to my problem.  My issue now is getting a copy of the master view that I want to magnify without using contexts.

Comment: Presumably the code exists in your app to generate that view in the first place. Can't you just run the same methods again to get a copy of it? Or deep copy its subviews into another view by just looping through the subviews and generating new views of the same type with the same properties?

Comment: Alternatively, grab a copy of it into an image view using renderInContext, but then magnify that image view using the view transform technique. That way the performance hit of copying the image only happens once instead of every frame while you're panning and zooming and will be much less noticeable.

Comment: Did all that, it works but only slightly better.  See, I can't get around refreshing the context every split second since it has to magnify a pickerView value in real time.  Since pickerViews don't have an event for simple touch and drags, I'm forced to throw the updates in timers.  I'm also drawing to 5 different views at the same time.  So while I'm only rendering one context every loop, I'm also manipulating it and drawing the result for each of the 5 values.  This must simply be too much and my answers may lie in either OpenGL or GDC.

Comment: I doubt it to be honest. It seems your bottleneck is the renderInContext method, and you can neither call that on a background thread (UIKit is single threaded) nor rewrite it using OpenGL (unless your plan is to replace UIPickerView with an identical version written in OpenGL). I think you may need to change your user interface concept to something more achievable.